# include any document as attachment in share point 2010 email

Tags: email

how to send any document as attachment in the email in share point.
On click of button, email with attachment should be sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Dot Net System.Net.Mail

```
//Get the Sharepoint SMTP information from the SPAdministrationWebApplication
string smtpServer = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.OutboundMailServiceInstance
.Server.Address;
string smtpFrom = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.OutboundMailSenderAddress;
//Create the mail message and supply it with from and to info
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(smtpFrom, insert_receiver);

//Set the subject and body of the message
mailMessage.Subject = insert_subject;
mailMessage.Body = insert_body;

//Download the content of the file with a WebClient
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

//Supply the WebClient with the network credentials of our user
webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

//Download the byte array of the file
byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(insert_ attachment_url);

//Dump the byte array in a memory stream because
//we can write it to our attachment
MemoryStream memoryStreamOfFile = new MemoryStream(data);

//Add the attachment
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStreamOfFile, insert_filename_attachment, insert_content_type));

//Create the SMTP client object and send the message
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

[SOURCE](http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2007/10/02/how-to-send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-from-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks @Nadeem Yousuf, i used document/pdf for insert_content_type for including pdf as attachment, but when i get the mail, it is not in pdf format, can anybody let me know, how to include pdf as attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "SharePoint 2010 - Send Email With Attachment" custom WF activity.
http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/